# Hibernate/Spring boot: add a variable with optional value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I would like a little tip on how you can make the value of a variable optional. To make this happen, the value of the variable name (optional) I did not pass as an argument in the saveproduct() method.
When I try its execution on Postman and insert the respective values of the variables productcode, name and photo (the latter of type Blob) even if I try to insert the value of name I always get null.
What I'm wondering is this: is it necessary to pass the variable name as an argument and possibly set it manually to null? Since then I have to create a form later, if I leave the relevant field blank, is it automatically set to null?
Can you suggest me to do something else?

Thank you all

Product.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import Model.Product;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String prodcode; 
    private String name; 
    
    @Lob
      private byte[] photo;

      public Product() {
      }

      public Product(String prodcode, byte[] photo) {
        this.prodcode = prodcode;
        this.name = name;
        this.photo = photo;
      }

    public String getProdcode() {
        return prodcode;
    }

    public void setProdcode(String prodcode) {
        this.prodcode = prodcode;
    }

    public byte[] getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }
```

Product_DAO_Imp.java

```
package DAO;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import Model.Product;

@Repository
public class Product_DAO_Imp  implements Product_DAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    @Override
    public boolean saveProduct(Product product) {
        boolean status=false;
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(product);
            status=true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
    
          
  // ....
  // ....
  // ....

    

}
```

Product_Service_Imp

```
package Service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import java.io.IOException;

import DAO.Product_DAO;
import Model.Product;

@Service
@Transactional
public class Product_Service_Imp implements Product_Service {
 
    @Autowired
    private Product_DAO productdao;
    
    @Override
    public boolean saveProduct(String prodcode, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        Product product = new Product(prodcode, file.getBytes());
        
        return productdao.saveProduct(product);
    }
    
          
  // ....
  // ....
  // ....

    
}
```

Controller.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import Model.Product;
import Service.Product_Service;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private Product_Service productservice;
    
    @PostMapping("save-product")
    public boolean saveProduct(@RequestParam ("prodcode") String prodcode, @RequestParam ("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
         return productservice.saveProduct(prodcode, file);
        
    }
    
  // ....
  // ....
  // ....
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the **name** field be optional while calling the **/api/save-product** endpoint in the above code, using the required=false like below in your controller could serve the purpose

```
@PostMapping("save-product")
public boolean saveProduct(@RequestParam("prodcode") String prodcode,
                           @RequestParam ("file") MultipartFile file,
                           @RequestParam(required = false) String name
) throws IOException {
    return productservice.saveProduct(prodcode, file,name);
}
```

Comment: can you kindly answer this question? thank you                                                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648343/hibernate-spring-boot-when-i-update-a-product-i-successfully-update-the-vari

Comment: Answered, pls check